# How to get class level annotation value using Java reflect?

Tags: java, class, reflection, annotations

I am writing a function which takes Class instance as a parameter. I want to get value of a specific annotation defined over a class.
Class:

```
@AllArgConstructor
@MyAnnotation(tableName = "MyTable")
public class MyClass {
    String field1;
}
```

Function that want to retrieve annotation value.

```
public class AnnotationValueGetter{

    public String getTableName-1(Class reflectClass){
        if(reflectClass.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class)!=null){
            return reflectClass.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class).tableName();
//This does not work. I am not allowed to do .tableName(). Java compilation error


        }
    }

    public String getTableName-2{
         Class reflectClass = MyClass.class;
         return reflectClass.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class).tableName()
        //This works fine.`enter code here`
    }
}
```

MyAnnotation:

```
@DynamoDB
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Inherited
public @interface MyAnnotation {

    /**
     * The name of the table to use for this class.
     */
    String tableName();

}
```

Function getTableName-1 shows me compilation error whereas getTableName-2 works just fine. What am I doing wrong here? I want to implement function similar to getTableName-1.

Comment: please, add the code of @MyAnnotation

Comment: What is the exact compiler error message you get?

Comment: @SpaceTrucker Intellij is not allowing me to do .tableName(). Cannot resolve method tableName()

Answer (score 5):

you can access the values this way:

```
public class AnnotationValueGetter {

  public String getTableName1(Class reflectClass) {
    if (reflectClass.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)) {
     Annotation a = reflectClass.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
     MyAnnotation annotation = (MyAnnotation) a;
     return annotation.tableName();
    }
    return "not found";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Class with generic type argument :

```
 public String getTableName-1(Class<?> reflectClass){
       //Your code here.
}
```

And one more suggestion, 
its better to use `reflectClass.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)` instead of `reflectClass.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class)!=null` as a condition in if block.

Comment: Thanks for this. Have incorporated this in my code.